# DescribePixelFormat from windows crate always returns 0 when given PixelFormat to fill with "parameter is incorrect" (error 87)

Tags: winapi, opengl, rust, windows-rs

I am trying to use the windows crate to set and get the pixel format descriptor of a window. When I pass None to the PPFD parameter, the return value is something reasonable (the maximum pixel format index, it seems). However, when I try to pass it a pointer to a PFD to fill so that I can check what the actual result after the SetPixelFormat call was, I always get Win32 Error 87 (incorrect parameter), and the PFD has not been modified by the function.

I am new to rust, and so I am unfamiliar with how to pass pointers to C functions, or what the conventions are for the Windows crate in particular. I may be making a mistake there.

One of the other parameters might be incorrect as well, but they are much simpler and look alright when I see their values in the debugger. Fake_hdc is non-null. nBytes is 40. PFD_PIXEL_TYPE seems to have 11 as its value, which is what I expect.

As a result of calling DescribePixelFormat, I expect the PFD fields to be filled with non-zero values and for the return value to be non-zero.

Here is the code with the issue. I'm just trying to get something basic up and running.

```
let instance = unsafe { GetModuleHandleW(None).unwrap() };

// SECTION: fake window for initializing opengl
{
    let fake_window_class_name: &HSTRING = w!("Fake Window Class");
    let fake_window_name: &HSTRING = w!("Fake");

    let fake_window_class = WNDCLASSW {
        style: CS_OWNDC | CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW,
        lpfnWndProc: Some(fake_window_callback),
        hInstance: instance,
        lpszClassName: fake_window_class_name.into(),
        ..Default::default()
    };

    let register_result = unsafe { RegisterClassW(&fake_window_class) };
    if register_result == 0 {
        panic!("Faile to register initial window class");
    }

    let fake_window = unsafe {
        CreateWindowExW(
            WS_EX_APPWINDOW | WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
            fake_window_class.lpszClassName,
            fake_window_name,
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            HWND(0),
            HMENU(0),
            instance,
            Some(ptr::null_mut()),
        )
    };
    let fake_hdc = unsafe { GetDC(fake_window) };
    assert!(!fake_hdc.is_invalid());

    let pfd = PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR {
        nSize: size_of::<PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR>() as u16,
        nVersion: 1,
        dwFlags: PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,
        iPixelType: PFD_TYPE_RGBA,
        cColorBits: 32,
        cDepthBits: 24,
        cStencilBits: 8,
        iLayerType: PFD_MAIN_PLANE,
        ..Default::default()
    };

    let pf_index = unsafe { ChoosePixelFormat(fake_hdc, &pfd) };
    assert!(pf_index != 0);

    let set_pixel_format_result = unsafe { SetPixelFormat(fake_hdc, pf_index, &pfd) };
    assert!(set_pixel_format_result.as_bool());

    let mut resulting_pfd = PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR {
        nSize: size_of::<PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR>() as u16,
        nVersion: 1,
        ..Default::default()
    };
    let get_pixel_format_result = unsafe {
        DescribePixelFormat(
            fake_hdc,
            PFD_PIXEL_TYPE { 0: pf_index as i8 },
            size_of::<PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR>() as _,
            Some(&mut resulting_pfd),
        )
    };
    if get_pixel_format_result == 0 {
        let last_error = unsafe { GetLastError() };
        println!("get pixel format failed: {:?}", last_error);
    } else {
        println!("Pixel format: {:?}", resulting_pfd);
    }

    let release_result = unsafe { ReleaseDC(fake_window, fake_hdc) };
    assert_eq!(release_result, 1);
    let destroy_result = unsafe { DestroyWindow(fake_window) };
    assert!(destroy_result.as_bool());
    let unregister_result = unsafe {
        UnregisterClassW(fake_window_class.lpszClassName, instance)
    };
    assert!(unregister_result.as_bool());
}
```

Comment: `ChoosePixelFormat` and `SetPixelFormat` can fail, but you aren't evaluating those return values. Start by looking at what `pf_index` is returned.

Comment: Thanks. `pf_index` is 11. I added checks on the return values from `ChoosePixelFormat` and `SetPixelFormat`. They both return success values, and `DescribePixelFormat` fails in the same way as before.

Comment: One thing to note: `PFD_PIXEL_TYPE` input for `DescribePixelFormat` is wrong, in win32 API, this is an `int`. There is also a bug report for this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/win32metadata/issues/1383

Comment: @derhass Thank you. I thought this was a strange windows rust crate thing that I didn't understand. Would you like to answer the question so that I can accept it?

Comment: @Trevor well, I posted this as a comment because I don't think it solves the issue - an 8 bit integer should be passed the same way as an 32 bit int under default win32 `stdcall` conventions. If this actually _does_ solve the issue, then there mightt be going something on on the rust side which I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a comment, I saw that the DescribePixelFormat function in the windows crate wasn't performing any conversion on the iPixelFormat parameter. The docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-describepixelformat) suggest that this should be an int, and instead it passes the single-valued PFD_PIXEL_TYPE (which I think is a single-value tuple) without conversion. I am not sure why, but this seems to cause the issue.

Here is the binding from the windows crate

```
#[doc = "*Required features: `\"Win32_Graphics_OpenGL\"`, `\"Win32_Graphics_Gdi\"`*"]
#[cfg(feature = "Win32_Graphics_Gdi")]
#[inline]
pub unsafe fn DescribePixelFormat<'a, P0>(hdc: P0, ipixelformat: PFD_PIXEL_TYPE, nbytes: u32, ppfd: ::core::option::Option<*mut PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR>) -> i32
where
    P0: ::std::convert::Into<super::Gdi::HDC>,
{
    #[cfg_attr(windows, link(name = "windows"))]
    extern "system" {
        fn DescribePixelFormat(hdc: super::Gdi::HDC, ipixelformat: PFD_PIXEL_TYPE, nbytes: u32, ppfd: *mut PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR) -> i32;
    }
    DescribePixelFormat(hdc.into(), ipixelformat, nbytes, ::core::mem::transmute(ppfd.unwrap_or(::std::ptr::null_mut())))
}
```

And here is the binding I wrote that seems to work without the wrong parameters error

```
fn describe_pixel_format(
    hdc: HDC,
    ipixelformat: i32,
    nbytes: u32,
    ppfd: *mut PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR,
) -> i32 {
    #[cfg_attr(windows, link(name = "windows"))]
    extern "system" {
        fn DescribePixelFormat(
            hdc: HDC,
            ipixelformat: i32,
            nbytes: u32,
            ppfd: *mut PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR,
        ) -> i32;
    }
    unsafe {
        DescribePixelFormat(
            hdc,
            ipixelformat,
            nbytes,
            ::core::mem::transmute(ppfd),
        )
    }
}
```